# Напечатать слова в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c

Дана строка, содержащая от 1 до 30 слов, в каждом из которых от 1 до 5 строчных латинских букв; между соседними словами – запятая, за последним словом – точка. Напечатать:
Все слова в алфавитном порядке
Вот что у меня получилось сделать это разделить слова и записать их в новый массив, если кто может пояснить или написать, как сделать, буду очень признателен:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "string.h"
    #include "stdio.h"

    void razbit(char *str,char slova[30][11],int *nn);
    void sort(char *str);

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        char s[350] = {"fesa,tre,qwrp,kjfo,aks,ptfgdr,odjhf,bckjd,abgfs.\n"};
        char slova[30][11];
        int i, n = 30;
        gets(s);
        razbit(s, slova, &n);

        return 0;
    }
    void razbit(char*str,char slova[30][11],int *nn)
    {       
        int n,i,j;
        char *s, *p = str; 
         n = *nn; 
            for(;*p != '.';) 
            {
                while((*p != '.') && (*p == ','))
                    p++; 
                    s = p; 
                if (*s != '.') 
                {
                    p = strstr(s, ","); 
                    if (p == NULL) 
                        p = strstr(s, "."); 
                        j = p - s; 
                        strncpy(slova[n], s, j);
                        slova[n][j]='\0';
                        n++; 
                }
            }
        *nn = n;
    }
```

Comment: Выделите код и нажмите на кнопочку {}. Так его читать не возможно.

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread275728.html

Answer (score 1):

Немного более общий, чем в задании, случай.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

// разбиваем на слова "на месте" (если '.' пропущена, то завершаемся также по '\n') 
// Returns массив указателей на слова (в куче) и количество слов
char **
split (char *s, int *pn)
{
  char **arr = 0;
  int c, cur = 0, n = 0, incr = 30;

  do {
    if (n + 2 > cur)
      arr = realloc(arr, (cur += incr) * sizeof(*arr));
    arr[n++] = s;
    while ((c = *s) && *s != ',' && *s != '.' && *s != '\n')
      s++;
    *s++ = 0;
  } while (!(c == 0 || c == '.' || c == '\n'));

  arr[*pn = n] = 0;
  return arr;
}

// это функция для qsort() (см. man 3 qsort)
static int 
cmp (const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  return strcmp(*(char **)p1, *(char **)p2);
}

static void
print (char *a[])
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; a[i]; i++)
    printf("%s%c", a[i], a[i + 1] ? ' ' : '\n');
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char **arr = 0;
  int n = 0;
  char in[LINE_MAX];

  while (fputs("enter: ", stdout), fflush(stdout),
         fgets(in , sizeof(in), stdin)) {
    arr = split(in, &n);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    print(arr);
    free(arr); 
  }

  return puts("\nend") == EOF;
}
```

Сортируем массив указателей, сами слова не двигаем.

Надеюсь, чем-то будет полезен. Например, как в чистом Си можно делать динамические массивы.

**UPD**

Еще несколько полезных для подобных задачек функций

```
// Отрезает правые пробелы в строке нулем (nil).
// Returns указатель на первый непробельный символ.  Строка может стать пустой.
char *
trim (char *s)
{
  while (isspace(*s))
    s++;
  if (*s) {
    char *t = s + strlen(s) - 1;
    while (t > s && isspace(*t))
      t--;
    *(t + 1) = 0;
  }

  return s;
}

// trim() для всех элементов NULL-terminated массива строк
void
trim_arr (char *a[])
{
  for (; *a; a++)
    *a = trim(*a);
}

// Сдвигает непустые элементы NULL-terminated массива строк влево.
// Returns их количество. 
int
shrink_arr (char *a[])
{
  int i, j = 0;

  for (i = 0; a[i]; i++)
    if (*a[i])
      a[j++] = a[i];
  a[j] = a[i]; // NULL array delimiter

  return j;
}
```

Теперь main может выглядеть, например, так

```
int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char **arr = 0;
  int n = 0;
  char in[LINE_MAX];

  while (fputs("enter: ", stdout), fflush(stdout),
         fgets(in , sizeof(in), stdin)) {
    arr = split(in, &n);
    trim_arr(arr);
    n = shrink_arr(arr);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    print(arr);
    free(arr); 
  }

  return puts("\nend") == EOF;
}
```

а ввод данных и их вывод, вот так:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
enter:   1,, 0a, zz, xxx , 22 88  .
0a,1,22 88,xxx,zz.
enter: 
end
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

это я немного `print()` изменил

```
static void
print (char *a[])
{
  for (; *a; a++) 
    printf("%s%c", *a, *(a + 1) ? ',' : '.');
  puts("");
}
```

Comment: О, сразу видно стиль опытного сишника!

Answer (score 0):

На Java я бы сделал так

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] words = { "1blablabla, blablabla.", "2blablabla, blablabla." };

for (int i = 0; i != words.length; i++) {
    data.add(words[i]);
}

Collections.sort(data); //получаем отсортированный по имени ArrayList<String>
```

Посмотрите, мб в C++ будет что-то похожее. Также посмотрите [здесь](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130102034450AAWjohG), должно помочь.

Comment: У вас спрашивают алгоритм на C++, а Вы в ответ пишите :"в java есть готовый метод сортировки в стандартной библиотеке Collections.sort() жеж" 
...

Comment: @wwvv: Что характерно, и в C тоже есть готовый метод сортировки в стандартной библиотеке[.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот вам ещё вариант на C#:

```
string.Join(',', line.TrimEnd('.').Split(',').OrderBy(w => w)) + "."
```